# bwWrappers and Black & White Picture problems

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I have created the following website http://www.nabresco.com from an html based theme.
Im definitely no expert in coding bit i figured my way out in order to edit it to my needs.

The website is up and running now and is looking good.

There is only one problem left that i cannot seem to figure out.

The pictures in the galleries are acting as if they are black and white and become coloured only when the cursor is on the actual selected picture. This is happening on some coputers and on others im viewing it normally (weird?).

I want to change them to all be colored all the time without having this black and white effect.

The code on the html for these pictures is as follows (showing first pic in the gallery code):

<div class="preloader">
                        <a class="bwWrapper single-image plus-icon" href="images/projects/al-rawi/5.png" rel="folio">
                            <img src="images/projects/al-rawi/5.png" alt="" >
                        </a>

This shows the pictures whith a plus sign that you can click on.

The css code is as follows:

```
/* -------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Images
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

.single-image {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.bwWrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
```

im quite lost now as i dont know if there is something that i need to change from the CSS file or not.

Thank you,

Rashed

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
.BWfade{
display:none!important;
}
```

Should work. (tested in Firefox)